# Selenium is having trouble interacting with DevExpress

Tags: selenium, devexpress

I am attempting to run the tool `Selenium` (with `IEDriverServer`) on an `IE` Browser application.  The application is made out of `DevExpress` components.

One component of the application in particular is a `GridView`.  This is a large component, and it contains numerous nested sub-components, such as header combo boxes, peripheral buttons, peripheral text fields, as well as a data grid of rows+columns.

In using `Selenium`, I am using such calls as

```
 "<WebElement>.click()", "<WebElement>.getText()" and "<WebElement>.sendKeys()"
```

on these `DevExpress` sub-components.

However, there is a general problem that these `DevExpress` sub-components (many times) do not react to the `Selenium` calls.

I am wondering if there's a different approach in getting Selenium to particularly operate on `DevExpress` components.  Perhaps, there's some type of overall setting to be performed.

If anyone has insight into this, I would appreciate their information.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the HTML code of those components?

Comment: Here is the explanation of this problem: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q585784

Comment: One code is this button, where often the Selenium "click()" yields no reaction.

<input value="" onfocus="aspxBGotFocus('splMain_ContentPlaceHolder1_cpCallbackPanelForGrid_gvGrid_PagerBarB_LastButton_0')" type="submit" name="_ctl0:splMain:ContentPlaceHolder1:cpCallbackPanelForGrid:gvGrid:PagerBarB:TC:LastButton" readonly="readonly" style="border-width:0px;height:0px;width:0px;padding:0;border-width:0;width:1px;height:1px;opacity:0;margin:0;position:relative;">

Comment: One type of code is this text box, where Selenium's "getText()" cannot acquire the text.

<input class="dxeEditArea_Office2010Blue dxeEditAreaSys " 
(Note: there are lengthy values for the inner tags "onblur", "onfocus", "onkeypress", "onkeydown" and "type").